# In ant, how to apply a target on a list of files (without ant-contrib)?

Tags: ant

Basically, I would like to mimic `apply` task but instead of passing to it an`executable`, I would like to pass an ant task and come up with something like:

```
<project>
   <target name="my-task">
      <!--target definition-->
   <target/>
   <target name="my-task-on-files">
        <apply task="my-task">
        <srcfile/>
        <targetfile/>
        <fileset dir="." includes="*.xml"/>
    </apply>
  </target>
</project>
```

The problem is that `apply` has to `task` attribute but only `executable`.

I need a solution that doesn't require `ant-contrib`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No native solution in ANT. This is the sort of problem **ant-contrib** was invented to solve :-(

Basically, ANT was designed to be extended by writing custom tasks to solve non-standard build problems....

Personally, I think once your build needs complex logic, it's time to embed a full blown programming language. My tool of choice is [groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/The+groovy+Ant+Task), due to it's tight integration with ANT. Furthermore, I use [ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) to manage my build's 3rd party dependencies, so automatically adding groovy to the classpath is no hardship.